# What does mean “realitas objectiva” in scholastic ontology?

Tags: ontology, theology, scholastic

Descartes uses the term in his third meditation (Med. III) to demonstrate the existence of God, [see a previous question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/105776/what-logical-arguments-have-been-made-to-say-an-effect-cannot-be-greater-than-it).

The term “realitas objectiva” is a technical term from scholastic ontology.

- How is the term defined, how does it apply, which explanatory power
  does the concept have?
- Can you give a reference?
- Why God is considered the “ens realissimum”?

I would appreciate any help from experts in scholastic theology.

Comment: Descartes appropriated the concept of objective reality specifically from scholastic realism of Duns Scotus. Philosophy Major gives a [detailed comparison](https://philosophymajor.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/objective-reality-descartes-debt-to-john-duns-scotus-in-the-third-meditation/) of what it meant to the two of them.

Comment: "scholastic" is not an easy topic... In a nutshell, an "idea" (concept) has "formal reality" when it is considered as a product of the mind (a "mental object") and has "objective reality" when it is considered wrt the object it represents. See [Formal versus Objective Reality in Descartes](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/formal-versus-objective-reality-in-descartes).

Comment: See also [Descartes: Ideas and The Formal-Objective Reality Distinction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-ideas/#ideasmodes): "When speaking of ideas as representing things to the mind, Descartes will refer to an idea’s *objective reality*. The objective reality of a thing is the kind of reality a thing possesses in virtue of its being a representation of something."

Comment: And see [Being, Formal versus Objective](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/cambridge-descartes-lexicon/being-formal-versus-objective/EB7DDBF4A3D9BB7E42383E17BCBE5D60) into *The Cambridge Descartes Lexicon*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Concerning your comment in a nutshell: It seems like much ado about nothing: formal reality = the concept in the mind; objective reality = the referent of the concept in the external world. - Many thanks for your support with all your references - I will look them up; at least some of them :-)

Answer (score 1):

Heidegger describes an inversion of meaning of realitas objectiva from Descartes and Scholasticism to Kant and modernism (depending on your subscription), in *The Basic Problems of Phenomenology*, Chapter One [Kant's Thesis: Being Is Not A Real Predicate](https://books.google.gg/books?id=VmatHCLJ4Q4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA37#v=onepage&q&f=false) p. 37–38.

> [Kant] separates objective reality as actuality from possibility. If I
> devise or invent some possible thing, then in doing so I am occupied
> with this imagined thing's pure relationships having real content,
> though without thinking of the thing with these relations as being
> actual, presently existent. In retrospect, this use of reality occurs
> also in Descartes. Descartes says, for instance, that error, and in
> general everything that has negative value, everything malum, non esse
> quid reale, is nothing.<sup>11</sup> This does not mean that error does not
> actually exist; instead, error is surely actual, but it and everything
> evil and bad is not a res in the sense that it would be an independent
> real content for itself. It is always only advenient and it *is* only
> by means of the negation of an independent real content, by the
> negation of the good. Similarly in the proof for God's existence in
> the third meditation, when he is speaking of realitas objectiva and
> realitas actualis, Descartes here, too, takes realitas in the sense
> mentioned above—the sense of realness or res-ness, German
> Sachheit—equivalent to the Scholastic quidditas [whatness,
> somethingness]. Realitas objectiva is not identical with the Kantian
> objective reality but just the opposite. In Descartes realitas
> objectiva means, following Scholasticism, the objectified what, which
> is held over against me only in pure representation, the essence of a
> thing. Realitas objectiva equals possibility, possibilitas. In
> contrast, what corresponds to the Kantian concept of objective
> reality, or actuality, is the Cartesian and Scholastic concept of
> realitas actualis—the what which is actualized (actu). This noteworthy
> distinction between the Cartesian concept of realitas objectiva as
> tantamount to subjectively represented possibility and the Kantian
> concept of objective reality, or that which is in itself, is connected
> with the fact that the concept of the objective [Objektive] was turned
> into its exact opposite during this period. The objective, namely,
> that which is merely held over against me, is in Kantian and modern
> language the subjective. What Kant calls the subjective is for the
> Scholastics that which lies at the basis, hupokeimenon, the objective,
> thus corresponding to the literal sense of the expression "subject."
>
> 11. Descartes, *Meditationes de prima philosophia*, Latin-German edition (Felix Meiner, 1959). Meditation 4, p. 100.

Ens realissimum is mentioned earlier on page 37 and on page 148.